# Flyway - Create users with password in the postgres database using flyway by referring username and password from AWS ssm parameter and secrets manage

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I am currently using ansible to create users with password in the AWS postgres database by referring the username and password stored in ssm parameter and secrets manager respectively.

We are migrating to another AWS account and are implementing flyway for db migration. We need to create the db users with passwords.

Is there a way in flyway to create the db users and passwords by referring the usernames and passwords stored in ssm parameter and secrets manager respectively ?

Comment: A Flyway migration SQL file cannot use any external data sources except the database it runs against. However, you can create a Flyway migration file programmatically. So, you might want to write a script fetching your data from the secret manager and put them out to a SQL file which you then use as a Flyway migration.

Answer (score 4):

Flyway supports [placeholders](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/placeholders) that can be used to pass custom values into sql scripts

```bash
flyway -placeholders.db_user=${DB_USER} -placeholders.db_user_pw=${DB_USER_PASSWORD} ...
```

You can reference these placeholders in SQL like this:

```sql
CREATE ROLE ${db_user} LOGIN PASSWORD '${db_user_pw}';
```

DB_USER and DB_USER_PASSWORD are environment variables and should be wired during the deployment to get values from AWS SSM using deployment tool capabilities.